WebRTC localhost demo failed
I need help debugging why this WebRTC demo is failing on my machine (demo is linked below). I'm receiving a WebRTC: ICE failed, add a STUN server. STUN is not required for this demo, there's something else wrong. The expected behavior is Ping/Pong messages being added to the document, it works on other machines I tested. I generated these reports using the WebRTC debugging tools and it seems like one of the peers isn't adding remote candidates:
System Info
Google Chrome 126.0.6478.126
6.9.9-arch1-1
Remote Peer
{
  "bandwidthEstimations": [],
  "codecStats": [],
  "dataChannelStats": [],
  "iceCandidatePairStats": [],
  "iceCandidateStats": [
    {
      "id": "82fe4016",
      "timestamp": 1721113775337,
      "type": "local-candidate",
      "address": "94122988-52d3-4ea5-a908-1e13aa1cbfae.local",
      "candidateType": "host",
      "port": 40425,
      "priority": 2122252543,
      "protocol": "udp",
      "proxied": "non-proxied",
      "transportId": "transport_0"
    },
    {
      "id": "cba3e367",
      "timestamp": 1721113775337,
      "type": "local-candidate",
      "address": "94122988-52d3-4ea5-a908-1e13aa1cbfae.local",
      "candidateType": "host",
      "port": 59502,
      "priority": 2105524479,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "proxied": "non-proxied",
      "transportId": "transport_0"
    }
  ],
  "inboundRtpStreamStats": [],
  "mediaSourceStats": [],
  "outboundRtpStreamStats": [],
  "peerConnectionStats": [
    {
      "id": "{635302bf-cf69-4c11-8b4f-5da2dc470498}",
      "timestamp": 1721113775337,
      "type": "peer-connection",
      "dataChannelsClosed": 0,
      "dataChannelsOpened": 0
    }
  ],
  "rawLocalCandidates": [
    "host(IP4:192.168.50.163:40425/UDP)",
    "host(IP4:192.168.50.163:59502/TCP) active"
  ],
  "rawRemoteCandidates": [],
  "remoteInboundRtpStreamStats": [],
  "remoteOutboundRtpStreamStats": [],
  "rtpContributingSourceStats": [],
  "trickledIceCandidateStats": [],
  "videoFrameHistories": [],
  "videoSourceStats": [],
  "browserId": 104,
  "closed": false,
  "configuration": {
    "bundlePolicy": "balanced",
    "certificatesProvided": true,
    "iceServers": [],
    "iceTransportPolicy": "all",
    "peerIdentityProvided": false
  },
  "iceRestarts": 0,
  "iceRollbacks": 0,
  "offerer": false,
  "pcid": "{635302bf-cf69-4c11-8b4f-5da2dc470498} 1721113767404252 (id=169651208195 url=https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA7gQwJawLwwBQFsIC4ZgCuWARgKYBOAlDKgHwFlwwAKFIWSEZGFZEtBtygAVJFjIhCUXvwA0MHFSoAoUJFgAHAIy1GzAEoiAwizKVj4MGWBQk4DKvXQYmgEx7rhk",
  "sdpHistory": [
    {
      "errors": [],
      "isLocal": false,
      "sdp": "v=0\r\no=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-99.0 1029152975187548310 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 86:AD:02:07:2E:C7:A1:0E:83:93:31:0E:90:BB:18:09:76:2F:2B:6C:01:E5:3D:76:E8:94:99:E9:64:56:A5:A4\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=msid-semantic:WMS *\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=recvonly\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:2/recvonly urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:csrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=fmtp:109 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1\r\na=fmtp:101 0-15\r\na=ice-pwd:d605ad1e8348931a75408343a061aaa9\r\na=ice-ufrag:f116249b\r\na=mid:0\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000/1\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=ssrc:2810913796 cname:{be2562c8-23a8-44cc-bedd-d19a6ecb03a4}\r\nm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 120 124 121 125 126 127 97 98 123 122 119\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=recvonly\r\na=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=extmap:4 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset\r\na=extmap:6/recvonly http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay\r\na=extmap:7 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=fmtp:126 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1\r\na=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1\r\na=fmtp:120 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60\r\na=fmtp:124 apt=120\r\na=fmtp:121 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60\r\na=fmtp:125 apt=121\r\na=fmtp:127 apt=126\r\na=fmtp:98 apt=97\r\na=fmtp:119 apt=122\r\na=ice-pwd:d605ad1e8348931a75408343a061aaa9\r\na=ice-ufrag:f116249b\r\na=mid:1\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:122 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:122 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:122 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:122 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:122 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp-rsize\r\na=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000\r\na=rtpmap:124 rtx/90000\r\na=rtpmap:121 VP9/90000\r\na=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000\r\na=rtpmap:126 H264/90000\r\na=rtpmap:127 rtx/90000\r\na=rtpmap:97 H264/90000\r\na=rtpmap:98 rtx/90000\r\na=rtpmap:123 ulpfec/90000\r\na=rtpmap:122 red/90000\r\na=rtpmap:119 rtx/90000\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=ssrc:348888008 cname:{be2562c8-23a8-44cc-bedd-d19a6ecb03a4}\r\nm=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=ice-pwd:d605ad1e8348931a75408343a061aaa9\r\na=ice-ufrag:f116249b\r\na=mid:2\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=sctp-port:5000\r\na=max-message-size:1073741823\r\n",
      "timestamp": 1721113767511
    },
    {
      "errors": [],
      "isLocal": true,
      "sdp": "v=0\r\no=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-99.0 6776458397351780831 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 3E:67:A8:89:C9:0C:0F:2F:E8:12:0D:34:6F:A9:0D:94:E6:44:10:A3:A1:35:A4:09:62:73:8F:87:73:91:22:C0\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=msid-semantic:WMS *\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=inactive\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=fmtp:109 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1\r\na=fmtp:101 0-15\r\na=ice-pwd:15b6dc9472362a429f607e7522715c18\r\na=ice-ufrag:2cc65d03\r\na=mid:0\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000/1\r\na=setup:active\r\na=ssrc:1112269320 cname:{fb5f2486-aa00-4db6-bc6b-1a3760a94d03}\r\nm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 120 124 121 125 126 127 97 98 123 122 119\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=inactive\r\na=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=extmap:4 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset\r\na=extmap:7 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=fmtp:126 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1\r\na=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1\r\na=fmtp:120 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60\r\na=fmtp:124 apt=120\r\na=fmtp:121 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60\r\na=fmtp:125 apt=121\r\na=fmtp:127 apt=126\r\na=fmtp:98 apt=97\r\na=fmtp:119 apt=122\r\na=ice-pwd:15b6dc9472362a429f607e7522715c18\r\na=ice-ufrag:2cc65d03\r\na=mid:1\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:122 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:122 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:122 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:122 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:122 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp-rsize\r\na=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000\r\na=rtpmap:124 rtx/90000\r\na=rtpmap:121 VP9/90000\r\na=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000\r\na=rtpmap:126 H264/90000\r\na=rtpmap:127 rtx/90000\r\na=rtpmap:97 H264/90000\r\na=rtpmap:98 rtx/90000\r\na=rtpmap:123 ulpfec/90000\r\na=rtpmap:122 red/90000\r\na=rtpmap:119 rtx/90000\r\na=setup:active\r\na=ssrc:3398540456 cname:{fb5f2486-aa00-4db6-bc6b-1a3760a94d03}\r\nm=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=ice-pwd:15b6dc9472362a429f607e7522715c18\r\na=ice-ufrag:2cc65d03\r\na=mid:2\r\na=setup:active\r\na=sctp-port:5000\r\na=max-message-size:1073741823\r\n",
      "timestamp": 1721113767521
    }
  ],
  "timestamp": 1721113775337
}

Local Peer
{
  "bandwidthEstimations": [],
  "codecStats": [],
  "dataChannelStats": [],
  "iceCandidatePairStats": [],
  "iceCandidateStats": [
    {
      "id": "b4c77f7d",
      "timestamp": 1721113775337,
      "type": "local-candidate",
      "address": "8b39875d-4379-4ae4-bcb1-d19259261a34.local",
      "candidateType": "host",
      "port": 39119,
      "priority": 2122252543,
      "protocol": "udp",
      "proxied": "non-proxied",
      "transportId": "transport_0"
    },
    {
      "id": "a7927ec2",
      "timestamp": 1721113775337,
      "type": "local-candidate",
      "address": "8b39875d-4379-4ae4-bcb1-d19259261a34.local",
      "candidateType": "host",
      "port": 58364,
      "priority": 2105524479,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "proxied": "non-proxied",
      "transportId": "transport_0"
    }
  ],
  "inboundRtpStreamStats": [],
  "mediaSourceStats": [],
  "outboundRtpStreamStats": [],
  "peerConnectionStats": [
    {
      "id": "{65f263a7-a525-49be-bbe7-4f8091993d01}",
      "timestamp": 1721113775337,
      "type": "peer-connection",
      "dataChannelsClosed": 0,
      "dataChannelsOpened": 0
    }
  ],
  "rawLocalCandidates": [
    "host(IP4:192.168.50.163:39119/UDP)",
    "host(IP4:192.168.50.163:58364/TCP) active"
  ],
  "rawRemoteCandidates": [
    "",
    "candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 94122988-52d3-4ea5-a908-1e13aa1cbfae.local 40425 typ host",
    "candidate:1 1 TCP 2105524479 94122988-52d3-4ea5-a908-1e13aa1cbfae.local 9 typ host tcptype active"
  ],
  "remoteInboundRtpStreamStats": [],
  "remoteOutboundRtpStreamStats": [],
  "rtpContributingSourceStats": [],
  "trickledIceCandidateStats": [],
  "videoFrameHistories": [],
  "videoSourceStats": [],
  "browserId": 104,
  "closed": false,
  "configuration": {
    "bundlePolicy": "balanced",
    "certificatesProvided": true,
    "iceServers": [],
    "iceTransportPolicy": "all",
    "peerIdentityProvided": false
  },
  "iceRestarts": 0,
  "iceRollbacks": 0,
  "offerer": true,
  "pcid": "{65f263a7-a525-49be-bbe7-4f8091993d01} 1721113767402356 (id=169651208195 url=https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA7gQwJawLwwBQFsIC4ZgCuWARgKYBOAlDKgHwFlwwAKFIWSEZGFZEtBtygAVJFjIhCUXvwA0MHFSoAoUJFgAHAIy1GzAEoiAwizKVj4MGWBQk4DKvXQYmgEx7rhk",
  "sdpHistory": [
    {
      "errors": [],
      "isLocal": true,
      "sdp": "v=0\r\no=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-99.0 1029152975187548310 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 86:AD:02:07:2E:C7:A1:0E:83:93:31:0E:90:BB:18:09:76:2F:2B:6C:01:E5:3D:76:E8:94:99:E9:64:56:A5:A4\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=msid-semantic:WMS *\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=recvonly\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:2/recvonly urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:csrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=fmtp:109 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1\r\na=fmtp:101 0-15\r\na=ice-pwd:d605ad1e8348931a75408343a061aaa9\r\na=ice-ufrag:f116249b\r\na=mid:0\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000/1\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=ssrc:2810913796 cname:{be2562c8-23a8-44cc-bedd-d19a6ecb03a4}\r\nm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 120 124 121 125 126 127 97 98 123 122 119\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=recvonly\r\na=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=extmap:4 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset\r\na=extmap:6/recvonly http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay\r\na=extmap:7 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=fmtp:126 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1\r\na=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1\r\na=fmtp:120 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60\r\na=fmtp:124 apt=120\r\na=fmtp:121 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60\r\na=fmtp:125 apt=121\r\na=fmtp:127 apt=126\r\na=fmtp:98 apt=97\r\na=fmtp:119 apt=122\r\na=ice-pwd:d605ad1e8348931a75408343a061aaa9\r\na=ice-ufrag:f116249b\r\na=mid:1\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:122 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:122 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:122 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:122 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:122 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp-rsize\r\na=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000\r\na=rtpmap:124 rtx/90000\r\na=rtpmap:121 VP9/90000\r\na=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000\r\na=rtpmap:126 H264/90000\r\na=rtpmap:127 rtx/90000\r\na=rtpmap:97 H264/90000\r\na=rtpmap:98 rtx/90000\r\na=rtpmap:123 ulpfec/90000\r\na=rtpmap:122 red/90000\r\na=rtpmap:119 rtx/90000\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=ssrc:348888008 cname:{be2562c8-23a8-44cc-bedd-d19a6ecb03a4}\r\nm=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=ice-pwd:d605ad1e8348931a75408343a061aaa9\r\na=ice-ufrag:f116249b\r\na=mid:2\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=sctp-port:5000\r\na=max-message-size:1073741823\r\n",
      "timestamp": 1721113767408
    },
    {
      "errors": [],
      "isLocal": false,
      "sdp": "v=0\r\no=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-99.0 6776458397351780831 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 3E:67:A8:89:C9:0C:0F:2F:E8:12:0D:34:6F:A9:0D:94:E6:44:10:A3:A1:35:A4:09:62:73:8F:87:73:91:22:C0\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=msid-semantic:WMS *\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=inactive\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=fmtp:109 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1\r\na=fmtp:101 0-15\r\na=ice-pwd:15b6dc9472362a429f607e7522715c18\r\na=ice-ufrag:2cc65d03\r\na=mid:0\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000/1\r\na=setup:active\r\na=ssrc:1112269320 cname:{fb5f2486-aa00-4db6-bc6b-1a3760a94d03}\r\nm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 120 124 121 125 126 127 97 98 123 122 119\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=inactive\r\na=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=extmap:4 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset\r\na=extmap:7 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=fmtp:126 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1\r\na=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1\r\na=fmtp:120 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60\r\na=fmtp:124 apt=120\r\na=fmtp:121 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60\r\na=fmtp:125 apt=121\r\na=fmtp:127 apt=126\r\na=fmtp:98 apt=97\r\na=fmtp:119 apt=122\r\na=ice-pwd:15b6dc9472362a429f607e7522715c18\r\na=ice-ufrag:2cc65d03\r\na=mid:1\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:122 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:122 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:122 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:122 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:122 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp-rsize\r\na=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000\r\na=rtpmap:124 rtx/90000\r\na=rtpmap:121 VP9/90000\r\na=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000\r\na=rtpmap:126 H264/90000\r\na=rtpmap:127 rtx/90000\r\na=rtpmap:97 H264/90000\r\na=rtpmap:98 rtx/90000\r\na=rtpmap:123 ulpfec/90000\r\na=rtpmap:122 red/90000\r\na=rtpmap:119 rtx/90000\r\na=setup:active\r\na=ssrc:3398540456 cname:{fb5f2486-aa00-4db6-bc6b-1a3760a94d03}\r\nm=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=ice-pwd:15b6dc9472362a429f607e7522715c18\r\na=ice-ufrag:2cc65d03\r\na=mid:2\r\na=setup:active\r\na=sctp-port:5000\r\na=max-message-size:1073741823\r\n",
      "timestamp": 1721113767622
    }
  ],
  "timestamp": 1721113775337
}

Demo


const wait = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))
const p1 = new RTCPeerConnection()
const p2 = new RTCPeerConnection()
p1.onicecandidate = async e => {
    if (e.candidate) {
        await wait(100)
        p2.addIceCandidate(e.candidate)
    }
}
p2.onicecandidate = async e => {
    if (e.candidate) {
        await wait(100)
        p1.addIceCandidate(e.candidate)
    }
} 
p1.onnegotiationneeded = async () => {
    try {
        const offer = await p1.createOffer({
            offerToReceiveAudio: true,
            offerToReceiveVideo: true
        })
        await p1.setLocalDescription(offer)
        await wait(100)
        await p2.setRemoteDescription(offer)
        const answer = await p2.createAnswer({
            offerToReceiveAudio: true,
            offerToReceiveVideo: true
        })
        await p2.setLocalDescription(answer)
        await wait(100)
        await p1.setRemoteDescription(answer)
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}
p2.ondatachannel = e => {
    const channel = e.channel
    channel.onmessage = async e => {
        console.log("p2 received: " + e.data)
        await wait(2000)
        channel.send("pong")
    }
}
const channel = p1.createDataChannel("channel1")
channel.onopen = () => channel.send("ping")
channel.onmessage = async e => {
    log("p1 received: " + e.data)
    await wait(2000)
    channel.send("ping")
}

function log(msg) {
    const div = document.createElement("div")
    div.innerText = msg
    document.body.appendChild(div)
}
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html> 



